# var_export always shows NULL on variable with cURL handle

Tags: php, curl, php-5.6

Why `var_export` outputs different information about cURL handle than `echo` and `var_dump`? How can I output proper information about it using `var_export`?

Example:

```
$a = curl_init();
echo $a . "\n";
var_dump($a);
var_export($a);
```

Output:

```
Resource id #12 
resource(12) of type (curl) 
NULL
```

I'm using PHP 5.6.14

Comment: Please read the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php You can't export resources, so it returns NULL

Answer (score 2):

> `var_export` [o]utputs or returns a *parsable* string representation of a variable

In other words, it returns something that is valid PHP source code to represent the value; if you paste that into a .php file you can recreate the same value. There is no possible valid PHP source code literal representation of a resource. A resource can only be constructed using special functions and will always cease to be valid or exist when the script terminates. There's no way to express a resource as a literal in any way.